# Is there a way to DELETE notes by PHP without having their ID's assigned with them?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, crud, sql-delete

I'm making a web app exercise, where the registered user can log in and create notes. Now I'd like to add a function, that deletes a certain note if I click the "X" I'm about to add to their side, but I cannot really figure out how is it possible to identify a certain note created by this method, more precisely, that how can I return it's id to use for the delete query. 
Here is the site you can check the way it looks like now, below I'm gonna attach the way I've listed the comments. Thanks in advance!

http://laszlovaszi.com/mx_agency/index.php

```html
<?php
function confirm_query($result) {
 if (!$result) {
  die("Database query failed.");
 }
}

function find_notes_by_id($user_id) {
 global $connection;
 $row = array();
 
 $safe_user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user_id);
 
 $query = 'SELECT content ';
 $query .= 'FROM notes ';
 $query .= 'WHERE user_id = '.$safe_user_id;
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 
 confirm_query($result);
 
 $final_data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ // iterates over the result-set object to get all data
        $final_data[] = $row; //assigns value to the array
    }
 return $final_data;

}
?>

<div class="notes text-center">
     <?php
     $notes_set = find_notes_by_id($userRow['id']);
     if(empty($notes_set)){
      echo "No notes have been posted for this user yet.";
     } else {
      echo "<div class=\"notelist text-left\">";
      foreach($notes_set as $note){
       echo "<div class=\"note text-left\">";
       echo "● ";
       echo htmlentities($note['content']);
       echo "<br />";
       echo "</div>";
      }
      echo "</div>";
     }
     ?>
</div>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: It also looks like you're slowly writing your own ORM. Have you considered using an existing one like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/)?

Comment: Do you mean like the notes are my objects? - I'm sorry, I'm just a beginner :) I haven't really considered either of them, because first I thought it's smarter to learn to "hard-code" everything by myself, just so I can see through the way it works at the basics.

Comment: It's like learning to drive by starting in a workshop with nothing but parts and having to build your own car. If you don't know what a car looks like or how it should work you're probably going to build some other contraption and learn a lot about fundamentals but still won't know how to drive across town. An ORM will do a lot of heavy lifting for you, but you can still get down and dirty when you need to. Don't think of it as cheating. Think of it as getting the job done and learning when you *want* to, not because you have to.

Comment: That's actually an interesting approach, which has definitely widened my point of view! I'll check them out for sure!

Comment: As an example, [Laravel](http://laravel.com) will do a whole lot of stuff for you automatically that will take four or five years to fully absorb: SQL, XSS, CSRF protection, MVC separation, database abstraction, migrations, and so on. There's no bottom in learning about coding, eventually you'll need to learn about all this and more, but in good time. Be productive now and you'll feel good about learning more, rather than failing with fundamentals and barely being able to do anything. Stay productive, have fun, and learn whenever you can. Enjoy!

Comment: I have the same approach as you actually. In learning the basics, I want to be as close to native PHP as possible. Maybe @tadman is right and we're just life hard on ourselves.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Having a command of core PHP is an important skill, but don't think that not learning about frameworks makes you a better programmer: It doesn't. You're handicapping yourself in a huge way if you never leverage that enormous amount of community work and knowledge. PHP is very lucky to have a half dozen first-class frameworks. Most languages have one or two at most.

Comment: @tadman we don't disagree about the importance of framework. I wrote about how I chose to learn the basics.

Comment: @BeetleJuice It's a personal choice as to where you start, but don't forget to at least try out the various frameworks. They'll have a lot to teach you about how they solve problems, *especially* if you've had experience solving them using just core PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I'd like to add a function, that deletes a certain note if I click
>   the "X" I'm about to add to their side

Make the "X" a link to a javascript function that takes the note id and makes an ajax request to the server to delete the note.  The id would be placed in the function call while you render each note in your `foreach($notes_set as $note)` step.  The link could be written this way:

```
echo "<a onclick='deleteNote($note[id])'> X </a>";
```

When the user presses the "X", the `deleteNote()` function will execute.  This function would make an AJAX request to `delete.php?note=123` (123 is whatever PHP put in as `$note['id']`).

Here is an example in raw Javascript. If you use a framework such as JQuery, it's even simpler:

```
<script>
function deleteNote(noteID) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      //remove the note from the DOM and alert user of success
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?note="+noteID, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

In PHP, you can retrieve the note id with `$id = $_GET['note']`.  This value can then be used in your `DELETE` query.

Just remember to first verify the following before you delete:

- the user is authenticated
- the note id really belongs to that user

Otherwise, anyone will be able to delete everybody's notes.

Comment: If this link gets pre-fetched by a browser or spidered by a robot this is going to lead to bad times. A good framework will wall these off behind a form to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @tadman that's a great point! thanks. i'll edit a bit to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you, it seems logic and as basic as I want to make it. I like the solution, that the note id's would be rendered together with the notes themselves, I guess that's the part I missed! I'm gonna try it right away!

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! I'm just a bit confused, that how the id from the url got assignet into the $_GET['note']? I've realized though, the value of the $_GET['note'] is assigned in the url itself. How does that actually work?

Comment: @sklrboy The part of the URL after `?` is the query string. When a url has `example.com?name=john&id=7`, PHP will automatically parse the query string and build the `$_GET` array with keys and values. In this example, `$_GET['name'] = 'john'` and  `$_GET['id'] = 7`

Comment: Wow! That's a really useful info, what I dont know how could avoid my attention. Thanks a lot, you really helped me out today! :)